# Angular2 form value observable subscription

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, observable

I'm using the `valueChanges` value observable of angular2's `FormControl`/`FormGroup`/`FormArray` classes a lot, I know we always have to unsub from *"infinite"* valued observables, so I was wondering if this is the case with this observable, I'd also be glad to know a way I can find out by myself next time :)

Answer (score 1):

`valueChanges` will stream changes from the object until stopped.  So, yes, it is in essence an *infinite* observable.  Unlike, an observable from an HTTP call, which is a one time event and fires the observables `completed` function, `valueChanges` will never fire the `completed` function.  If you are calling `subscribe`, I would set it to unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy` function.

```
this.sub = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(....);


ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub) {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

By firing the completed function, I mean this:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
    data =>  //get data,
    error =>  /error happens,
    completed =>  //  <-- THIS NEVER FIRES IN A VALUECHANGES OBSERVABLE


);
```

Comment: So even if the actual form ceases to exist (when the component destroys), its valueChanges observable stays alive?

Comment: The way I understand it, in order to prevent memory leaks, all infinite observables need to be manually unsubscribed when the component is destroyed.  Whether the observable stays alive(I wouldn't think so) or just memory is not released properly(I think this is more likely the case), I'm not entirely sure to be honest.